# Does RegisterDeviceNotification require a GUI

Tags: windows, winapi, msdn

Does the Win32 api function, `RegisterDeviceNotification` require a GUI?

Will it work without a GUI?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires a window handle (or a service handle). The window handle may points to a hidden message-only window, so there is no GUI but there must be a message pump.

Comment: can you please explain me as i cant understand

Comment: do you say i must have a window

Comment: Yes, you must have a window, but it can be invisible to user (user doesn't see any GUI).

Comment: @barbgal: If you can create a windows without the `WS_VISIBLE` window style, the windows will be not seen.

Comment: Note that as @sergius correctly states, you don't need a window handle at all if you are running as a windows service, you just use your service handle.